# Angular - hashlocationstrategy - sharing link on linkedin with hash

Tags: angular, redirect, linkedin-api, hashtag

I'm using angular and hashlocationstrategy:

my default link to site is https://mywebsite.com/#/

if i want to share on LinkedIn a sub route from my website like https://mywebsite.com/#/123
the link show as https://mywebsite.com/ #/123

[image]

I tried to remove # but angular use this strategies to load the correct page
any idea to replace # or remove it and keep redirecting to the same point in angular ?

Comment: angular doesn't need hashlocationstrategy if you configure your backend properly with serving index.html on not found routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aakash commented, your choices are to:

1. Use hash location strategy and let Angular handle the routing
2. Don't use hash location strategy and set up your server to always serve index.html (or at least fall back to serving that if whatever x.html isn't found)

This is because browsers/servers ignore anything after #'s. That means that linking to `http://example.com/#/something` will load example.com's index.html page (or whatever the server is set up to serve as default). Once index is served, Angular loads, reads the route NOT ignoring everything after the # and proceeds to handle the routing.

Without #'s, going to the same `http://example.com/something` will attempt to load something.html, which for an angular app doesn't exist so the server will 404. The server needs to be set up to serve the base index.html in such events. Once said index is served, Angular loads, reads the route and proceeds to handle the routing.

Comment: Thank you, looks like i need to update my server code

Comment: anyway i fixed my problem by adding "/" before # 
to be something like http://example.com/#/something not http://example.com#/something

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't see that missing slash in your question. Without changing the strategy, that would indeed be the fix. ;)

Comment: Thank you, also your answer is good to think about it :)